# addEventListener didn't send the HTML input message to console

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I Have input field and button in HTML.

```
        <div class="chat-input" id="chat-input">

            <input type="text" id="input-msg" placeholder="Enter message..."/>

            <button class="send-btn" type="button" id="send-btn">
                <img src="send.png" alt="send-btn">
            </button>

        </div>
```

I create the constant for input section and button in client side javascript file.

```
   const user_send =document.querySelector("#send-btn");
    const user_msg=document.querySelector("#input-msg");
```

and add the eventlistener in send button.

```
user_send.addEventListener("submit",()=>{
    const msg = user_msg.value;
    console.log(msg);
});
```

But it does not send the value to the console.

I also try by getElementById but it doesnot work.

Comment: You are using a `<button>`, not an `<input type="submit">` inside a form. So your button does not have an event called `submit`, since that is a `<form>` event tied to a submit input. So use a `<form>` and a submit input if you need to use a submit event listener. Or add a onclick event to the button that will trigger the form.submit()

Answer (score 0):

replace
`addEventListener("submit"..`
by `user_send.addEventListener("click"`
When the user click on the button, your const get the value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    const user_send = document.querySelector("#send-btn");
    const user_msg = document.querySelector("#input-msg");

    user_send.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const msg = user_msg.value;
        console.log(msg);
    });
```

```html
    <div class="chat-input" id="chat-input">

        <input type="text" id="input-msg" placeholder="Enter message..." />

        <button class="send-btn" type="button" id="send-btn">
            <img src="send.png" alt="send-btn">
        </button>

    </div>
```